# how to export/print out classifier detailed outputs for each observation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, prediction

I have used 2 classifiers to predict learner's binary final results (success or fail):

```
clfs = [
        GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2,random_state=0),
        XGBClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2,random_state=0)
    ]
```

The below report the final overall measures of precision, recall, f1-score, support and accuracy -  but I was just wondering how to print out a CSV file of each observation whether it was predicted correctly or not (yes/No) along with the assigned learner ID

```
for clf in clfs:
print('Result of: ',clf)
train_and_cross_validation(clf)

print(rs.score(X_test,y_test))
y_pred = rs.predict(X_test)
report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
print(report)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing your variables, add them to a pandas dataframe, and then output that dataframe to a .csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create an empty dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Report":[0], 
"Confusion_Matrix":[0],
"Report":[0],
"RS_Value":[0],
"CLF":[0]})

for clf in clfs:
    print('Result of: ',clf)
    train_and_cross_validation(clf)

    rs_value = (rs.score(X_test,y_test))
    y_pred = rs.predict(X_test)
    report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
    print(report)
    confusion_m = (confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))

#Creates a new line for the dataframe from the data we just calculated
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Report":[report], 
    "Confusion_Matrix":[confusion_m],
    "RS_Value":[rs_value],
    "CLF":[clf]})

#adds that line onto the original dataframe
    df1 = df1.append(df2)
```

## After all the looping is done, outputs your results to a .csv file

```
df1.to_csv('output.csv')
```